# Laravel 4 Queue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've been using the Queue system in Laravel 4 and it works great! - I was wondering if there was a way to view what is actually in the Queue? I'm using redis for the back-end.

Comment: What did you mean by `in the Queue` ?

Comment: what ever has been queued and still waiting to be processed

Comment: Have you tried with php artisan queue:listen ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I spent some time on this digging around the Queue driver and the [API](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/). I was able to find an answer for you.

**Short TL;DR version:**

There is no native `Queue::getList()` (or similar) function on the Queue interface.

But this will get you a list of all queued jobs in your `default` Redis queue waiting to be processed:

```
$list = (Queue::getRedis()->command('LRANGE',['queues:default', '0', '-1']));
```

*change `default` to another name if you run multiple queue tubes.*

Be warned that command might result in a very large dataset being returned (its like dumping part of your database) - so you might just want to get the number of jobs queued instead:

```
 $queue_length = (Queue::getRedis()->command('LLEN',['queues:default']));
```

**Longer version**:

There is no native `Queue::getList()` (or similar) function on the Queue interface. But I noticed that it is possible to get the Redis driver from the Queue interface:

```
$redis = Queue::getRedis();
```

Digging into the Redis driver - we can see there is a function called `command()`. Which is defined as

```
command(string $method, array $parameters = array()) 
Run a command against the Redis database.
```

So that means we can now run any native Redis command through Laravel onto the Redis instance.

[A full list of Redis commands is here](http://redis.io/commands)

By browsing that list - we have a number of helpful commands which we can use for Queues.

Firstly - you can view all `KEYS` available - which might be useful if you are not sure of the name of your queues:

```
$keys = Queue::getRedis()->command('KEYS',['*']);
```

You can also make sure a specific KEY exists before running another operation - like this:

```
if (Queue::getRedis()->command('EXISTS',['queues:default']))
{
    // Queues:default key exists!
}
```

Also - you can get the length of the queue - which is useful

```
 $queue_length = (Queue::getRedis()->command('LLEN',['queues:default']));
```

And finally you can get the entire list of queues with this

```
 $list = (Queue::getRedis()->command('LRANGE',['queues:default1', '0', '-1']));
```

If you dont want the full list (perhaps your queue is quite large) - you can get a subset of it. [Read more a LRANGE at the Redis docs here](http://redis.io/commands/lrange).

Comment: @Ben Kilah - does that answer your question? Do you need any more info?

Comment: many thanks excellent answer, sorry I was late to the party! :)

Answer (score 0):

not exactly answer for your case but just as reference for others.

If you are using beanstalkd driver than you can access that information like this:

```
$stats = Queue::getPheanstalk()->stats();
```

where the stats variable will have these properties:

```
array(
   'current-jobs-urgent' => '0',
   'current-jobs-ready' => '5',
   'current-jobs-reserved' => '0',
   'current-jobs-delayed' => '0',
   'current-jobs-buried' => '0',
   'cmd-put' => '95',
   'cmd-peek' => '0',
   'cmd-peek-ready' => '130',
   'cmd-peek-delayed' => '32',
   'cmd-peek-buried' => '32',
   'cmd-reserve' => '0',
   'cmd-reserve-with-timeout' => '1142',
   'cmd-delete' => '90',
   'cmd-release' => '1124',
   'cmd-use' => '194',
   'cmd-watch' => '0',
   'cmd-ignore' => '0',
   'cmd-bury' => '0',
   'cmd-kick' => '0',
   'cmd-touch' => '0',
   'cmd-stats' => '37',
   'cmd-stats-job' => '32',
   'cmd-stats-tube' => '78822',
   'cmd-list-tubes' => '78822',
   'cmd-list-tube-used' => '0',
   'cmd-list-tubes-watched' => '0',
   'cmd-pause-tube' => '0',
   'job-timeouts' => '3',
   'total-jobs' => '95',
   'max-job-size' => '65535',
   'current-tubes' => '1',
   'current-connections' => '1',
   'current-producers' => '0',
   'current-workers' => '0',
   'current-waiting' => '0',
   'total-connections' => '40679',
   'pid' => '15937',
   'version' => '1.10',
   'rusage-utime' => '6.184000',
   'rusage-stime' => '16.808000',
   'uptime' => '146790',
   'binlog-oldest-index' => '0',
   'binlog-current-index' => '0',
   'binlog-records-migrated' => '0',
   'binlog-records-written' => '0',
   'binlog-max-size' => '10485760',
   'id' => '56d8d2c9888219bc',
   'hostname' => 'ddeath-pc',
)
```

so then for example `$stats['current-jobs-ready']` will return jobs ready to be processed by worker.